# github_actions Unable to run the "nohup java -jar" command

Tags: linux, github-actions

I tried to automate the deployment of the jar package with github actions, but in the last step (running the jar package), an error occurred.

[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz2ig.png)

Although it appears to be running the jar package, my server does not have a record of the operation of the jar package.

```bash
[root@VM-12-13-centos pet]# ps -ef | grep java
root     24116 32092  0 15:15 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto java
[root@VM-12-13-centos pet]#
```

**This is the code of my yml file**

```yaml
run_jar:
    name: run jar package
    needs: build_back
    runs-on: [self-hosted, linux, x64]
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash
        working-directory: /www/pet

    steps:
      - name: kill the old jar
        run: ps -ef | grep back.jar | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9

      - name: run new jar
        run: nohup java -jar back.jar &
```

What can I do to make my jar package run successfully?

Comment: Are you using a self-hosted runner? Normally, github actions run *on GitHub*, and what you're doing doesn't make any sense. Even when run locally, they aren't generally meant for starting long-running services.

Comment: change `nohup java -jar back.jar &` -> `java -jar back.jar`